# Why two variables(num1,num2) are not defined in the if statement

Tags: python, function, variables

Thanks to those helpful people yesterday who solved the try-catch error!
However, another error occurred. After the user_option not defined error is solved, when the user inputs an invalid option (like `list index out of range` error), the python program outputs another error while dealing with the list index out of range: `print("The divide is", num1, "/", num2, dividing(num1, num2)) NameError: name 'num1' is not defined`
The codes are the following:

```
if user_input == 0:
    user_option = None
    try:
        small_option = int(
        input("Which operation do you want to do? \n 1. Adding \n 2. Subtracting \n 3. Multiplying "
                  "\n 4. Dividing"))
        small_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        user_option = small_list[small_option-1]
     except IndexError:
         print("Invalid option")
         if user_option == 0:
             num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
             num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
         if user_option == 1:
             print("The sum is", num1, "+", num2, adding(num1, num2))
         elif user_option == 2:
             print("The subtraction is", num1, "-", num2, substract(num1, num2))
         elif user_option == 3:
             print("The multiplying is", num1, "*", num2, multiplying(num1, num2))
         else:
             print("The divide is", num1, "/", num2, dividing(num1, num2))
             break
```

This is the whole codes in the while loop for the calculator
Only the num1 and num2 in the add function went undefined.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your code is not indented properly, and does not run.

Comment: With that repaired, your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.  Also note that there is no such thing as an "if loop": a loop uses `while` or `for`.

Answer (score 1):

I found two reasons why the variables num1 and num2 are not read.

1.You gave 4 Calculator operations addition,subtraction,multiplication and division.The options are read as 1,2,3 and 4 for each operation respectively.Now you used a 'small_list' and made each index as 0,1,2,3 for each operation.
However at this line you are checking `if user_option == 0:` which will only be true when addition is selected and it will never run for other operations.Remove the if condition and take inputs no matter which operation is selected.

2.Now the second reason is all the code starting from `if user_option==0` is nested inside the `except IndexError` block .Thus it will never run unless an error occurs .Check this.